# How to optimize(reduce) the size of my android app

Tags: android, apk

I created an android app that contains just 2 webviews with some java script in them,an inbuilt PDF reader API which weighs around 2 MB and all the PDF's(Compressed) which are around 25 MB and other images(Also compressed) etc less than 1 MB which tallies to around 30 MB.So after generating the app my app size is around 55 MB.Which i believe is not acceptable.
So,why is my app having so much large size and also how can i even more reduce the size of my android app.

Comment: "why is my app having so much large size" -- dependencies, most likely. Use the APK Analyzer in Android Studio (Build > Analyze APK...) to find out where your space is going. "how can i even more reduce the size of my android app" -- find out where your space is going **first**. Then, and only then, worry about how to make it smaller.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your comment i did an APK Analysis and found out that the "lib" is 15 MB which is around 35% of my app size which is not acceptable as i had used only a single ext library of 2 MB.The rest folders are OK.now how can i resolve this any suggestions??

Comment: @CommonsWare this is what i am getting in APK analyser to be precise -https://postimg.org/image/d4jj4ynj1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> found out that the "lib" is 15 MB which is around 35% of my app size which is not acceptable as i had used only a single ext library of 2 MB

You miscounted the size of that library and its dependencies. Assuming that you are not using the NDK yourself, then either that library is using the NDK, or its dependencies are using that library. That library size roughly matches that of [this PDF viewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer), though I do not know if that is the specific one that you are using.

The documentation for that PDF viewing library has [a section on why the library makes your APK big](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#why-resulting-apk-is-so-big):

> Android PdfViewer depends on PdfiumAndroid, which is set of native libraries (almost 16 MB) for many architectures. Apk must contain all this libraries to run on every device available on market. Fortunately, Google Play allows us to upload multiple apks, e.g. one per every architecture. There is good article on automatically splitting your application into multiple apks, available [here](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/). Most important section is Improving multiple APKs creation and versionCode handling with APK Splits, but whole article is worth reading. You only need to do this in your application, no need for forking PdfiumAndroid or so.

Your options are:

- Follow the advice in the documentation and use ABI splits to have separate APKs per CPU architecture (which only helps if you are distributing by some means that supports separate APKs per architecture, such as the Play Store)
- Use [some other PDF rendering option](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html)
- Eliminate the PDF rendering feature from your app, relying on `ACTION_VIEW` and the user's chosen PDF viewer
- Eliminate the PDFs from your app, converting them to HTML/CSS/images and rendering them in a `WebView`

Answer (score 1):

Use Proguard. From build.gradle file enable Proguard like this,

```
  buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Then open your "proguard-rules.pro" and mention all the Rules. If you are not using any external libraries, then paste this in you "proguard-rules.pro" file.
.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}
```

If you are using Okhhtp for web service then use this too in your proguard-rules.pro

```
# For OkHttp3
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Annotation
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.* { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.*
```