# twilio chat sdk doubles the size of my app's APK

Tags: android, chat, twilio

Including the twilio android SDK doubles the size of our app( from around 10 MBs to around 20 MBs)

The main culprit are the platform specific `libtwilio-rtd-native.so` files.

Is there any way to reduce APK size ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41653908/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31122970/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100668/115145

Comment: Just use [splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html) to choose which native library you would like to use.